# Are fundamental particles more than their properties?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, elementary-particles

Parent questions:

[What came first, neutrons or electrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/479419/)

[Why saying that during electron capture the electron is converted to a neutrino?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/479433/)

Background: various nuclear phenomena show the transformation of a set of fundamental particles into others. In particular, an electron capture leads a proton plus an electron to a chain of events that result in a neutron and a neutrino. Or a proton produces a positron, a neutron, a neutrino, etc.

In their answer, The_Sympathizer says in the end hadrons are observed to be made of subparticles and neither of them is an electron, so this is proof the electron does not survive the process of electron capture (sorry if I don't use the right words).

Yet, during all of these nuclear reactions, there is conservation of a number of things, including energy, charge, and other things.

So if a particle in the standard model is defined through its properties (mass, charge, spin, etc) and if after a nuclear reaction, those properties are redistributed among the final products, why is it different to say that part of the initial particles are redistributed? Is it just that the relation is not bijective, i.e. that properties constitute a particle but particles are not a set of properties?

Comment: "Those properties are redistributed among the final products." They aren't though- not all properties are conserved. Particle number, strangeness, weak isospin, and lepton family number, just to name a few.

Comment: And they cannot be computed from others? They are orthogonal dimensions, so to speak?

Comment: No, they cannot be computed from others.

Comment: Great. Should I close the question then or is it still possible to get what you said in the form of an answer?

Comment: Actually, have you just answered yes to my question, i.e. that particles are more than their properties?

Comment: No, particles are defined by their properties. These properties are just not conserved in interactions. I admit I don't fully get what you are trying to ask here, or I would have just written an answer.

Comment: @Chris : However, one wouldn't necessarily expect _all_ properties one could think of, _to_ be conserved: e.g. particle number - if you can convert particles then having more or less of them afterward seems sensible - but this doesn't necessarily mean that the core idea here is wrong. In particular, it is not "is every _conceivable_ property conserved" but rather, "can we describe each fundamental particle _uniquely_ in terms of variable amounts of some set number of conserved properties?"

Comment: I answered in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93528/discussion-between-exocytosis-and-g-smith

Comment: In particular, such that those properties can be considered as basic "substances" of some form, which subsist wholly within packages known as particles, and for which all processes can then be considered as reapportionments/rearrangements thereof? This idea is rather similar to that from classical philosophies like those of ancient Greece and ancient India with the old system of the four classic elements (sometimes five, six).

Comment: I'd want to also say it should not be reasonable to necessarily expect that the Standard Model alone will be describable this way, since we know it cannot be the complete description of our Universe's physics.

Comment: It's (probably) more accurate to say that those properties are properties of the various fields; a particle is "just" a quantized excitation of a field.

Answer (score 1):

> So if a particle in the standard model is defined through its properties (mass, charge, spin, etc)

It is defined as [in the table](http://So%20if%20a%20particle%20in%20the%20standard%20model%20is%20defined%20through%20its%20properties%20(mass,%20charge,%20spin,%20etc)%20and%20if%20after%20a%20nuclear%20reaction,%20those%20properties%20are%20redistributed%20among%20the%20final%20products,%20why%20is%20it%20different%20to%20say%20that%20part%20of%20the%20initial%20particles%20are%20redistributed?%20Is%20it%20just%20that%20the%20relation%20is%20not%20bijective,%20i.e.%20that%20properties%20constitute%20a%20particle%20but%20particles%20are%20not%20a%20set%20of%20properties?) of elementary partices, and its interactions are defined, i.e. what happens when interacting with another elementary particle by [the forces defined between particles](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html), with various coupling strengths ( this is quantum mechanics, not classical mechanics) all defined by modeling observations with the mathematics of [quantum mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/qapp.html), in particular quantum field theory (example: [quantum electrodynamics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/qed.html) is one).

> and if after a nuclear reaction,

Nuclei are composites of elementary particles

> those properties are redistributed among the final products,

They are not redistributed, they  follow  the rules of the fundamental interactions, and the conservation laws, new particles may appear due to exchanges of quantum numbers. It is only the energy that is redistributed, and energy does not carry a particular particle label. It is the quantum number transfers or changes according to the interactions that will determine the new particle content.

> why is it different to say that part of the initial particles are redistributed? Is it just that the relation is not bijective, i.e. that properties constitute a particle but particles are not a set of properties?

The identity of an elementary particle is defined by the quantum numbers in the table and the mass. Thats all. Quantum numbers are reshuffled according to the rules, but there is no identity in the energy packets outside of that. If the rules are obeyed it has a probability to happen. The energy packet does not have a DNA carrying the originating particle identity, other than connection through quantum number conservation.

Comment: So basically, you are answering by the negative to the main question, right? i.e. that particles are no more than their properties.